# Box2D port for Haxe (JavaScript)

Tags: box2d, game-physics, haxe

I have downloaded and installed the library from the official Haxe site. But there is a problem: this port uses Flash libraries and doesn't want to compile to HTML+JS. Is there a solution?

Can you name another physical 2D engine for Haxe/JS: simple, correct, with samples?

Answer (score 3):

Nape is a really good Haxe physics library. http://napephys.com

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for the latest Box2D library, it seems like it should be cross-platform and framework agnostic. The sample has openfl-based code (though that should also compile for various targets.)

https://github.com/openfl/box2d

Nape was mentioned as an alternative. Here are some more recent links for the Nape engine:

- Github (recent fork): https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/nape-haxe4
- Haxelib: https://lib.haxe.org/p/nape-haxe4
- Project page: https://joecreates.github.io/napephys/